# In how many ways can you divide $12$ people in $5$ distinct groups?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Problem:
$12$ students are asked to go into the groups $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$. In how many ways can this division be done if there must at least one person per group?

I tried to approach this problem first by going through each possible group size. So for example, there could be group sizes $8, 1, 1, 1, 1$. There are $5$ ways to have this type of division. Then there are $12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9=\frac{12!}{8!}$ ways of dividing the students into this type of arrangement. So in total, we have $5\cdot\frac{12!}{8!}$ ways to do this.

However, this approach is problematic as it is quite cumbersome and bruteforcey as there are quite a lot of ways to do the group division (how many persons are in each group).

So, is there a more general way of doing/approaching this type of problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with Principle of Inclusion Exclusion?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I am. Somehow I had completely overlooked it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply inclusion - exclusion.

There are $5$ choices for each person, so $5^{12}$ total ways.

Applying inclusion-exclusion,

Total ways - at least one group empty + at least two groups empty -...

$5^{12} - \binom51 4^{12} + \binom52 3^{12} - \binom532^{12} + \binom541^{12}$

Answer (score 0):

See the [Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_s) and [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

First, count the number of ways to partition your $12$ distinct persons into $5$ unlabeled parts which is precisely what the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind are used to count, and then choose a labeling of the parts in the partition in $5!$ ways for a total of:
$$5!\cdot {12\brace 5}$$

The articles above give information on how you might choose to calculate the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind through various means, be it inclusion-exclusion or recurrence relations, or what else.